# How to get p-value from contrast?

Tags: stata, contrast

In Stata: how to get p-value from contrast?

Here is the code I am using to a contrast between members of `level2_enc`.

```
mixed pme i.level2_enc i.level3_enc i.question_enc || subject:,mle
contrast ar.level2_enc
```

The output is here,

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
               |   Contrast   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------+------------------------------------------------
pme            |
    level2_enc |
(HAS vs icon)  |   .0825242    .081987     -.0781674    .2432158
  (HS vs HAS)  |  -.1803932   .0815412      -.340211   -.0205755
   (SW vs HS)  |   .0479133   .0817379       -.11229    .2081166
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I wonder how do I get the p-values for each contrast, e.g. `(HAS vs icon)`? I checked the help file, and it seems that the p-values hide in something called `r(table)`, but I have no idea how to extract it.

Comment: `matrix list r(table)`

Comment: https://www.statalist.org/forums/help#spelling  STATA hasn't been the correct spelling for over 30 years.

Comment: You can most likely add the `pveffects` or the `effects' option to show the effects table with p-values. This is also explained in the help file and the pdf manual. Since you did not use a public dataset, this is hard to verify for sure. Perhaps you would consider writing up your own answer based on the suggestions in the comments.